# How to use holodeck with S3

Tags: amazon-s3, s3fs, b2b, rclone, goofys

I would like to use http://holodeck-b2b.org/ with a self-hosted S3-Storage as filesystem.
I'm thinking of mount options like Goofys, s3fs or rclone.
But also whether there is possibly any fork or addon to holodeck that would enable this natively.
Do anyone has experience with that ?
Or do anyone know something similar to holodeck for file to AS4 Communication ?

Comment: It may be out of date, you may consider using phase4 (https://github.com/phax/phase4) which has proven to work with S3.

Comment: And how did you get it to work with S3 ? As far as I can see only the path to the message folder can be configured and phase 4 is just working with the java File API.

Comment: Yes, but you can work on the InputStream level. Let's discuss this on https://github.com/phax/phase4/discussions - there we have a bit more space for elaboration.